# How do I change text on the line below a specified criteria in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I'm working with a Cisco switch and copying some vlans over from another configuration file.

It looks like this:

```
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/1

 switchport access vlan 502
```

I know what vlans they belong to, what I'm wanting to do is search for GigabitEthernet4/0/1 for example and replace the vlan value. There will be several on the same vlan, so I'd like to even potentially create something that does it automatically based on the specified criteria after i set it up once, or I can go through this find and replace process, just need to go one line down.

How could I go about doing this? I am assuming I will be using the Extended search mode or Regular expression mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, search using Regular Expression

Find:

```
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/1\r\n\r\n\sswitchport access vlan 502
```

Replace with:

```
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/1\r\n\r\n\sswitchport access vlan 507
```

This site may help a little with searching in Notepad ++

[Notepad Search](http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: Ok great, and since I don't care what vlan my find criteria is on can I specify a star or something similar? I only care that I'm on the right switch (GigabitEthernet4/0/1, 4/0/13, etc) This keeps me from having to keep referring back to the document.

Comment: If you do a .* it will take the rest of that line
Find: interface GigabitEthernet4/0/1\r\n\r\n\sswitchport access vlan.*